# File POSIX Capabilities

Tags: linux, kernel

In Linux kernel v2.6.~ there was an option `File POSIX Capabilities` in kernel configuration, which, in particular, is necessary to build and use [Linux Containers](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) successfully.

I'm currently using v3.9.4 kernel, and I can't find this option in kernel configuration. But LXC still requires it, so it doesn't seem it's already enabled by default. So where has it gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option was removed in [commit b3a222e52e4d4be](http://git.kernel.org/linus/b3a222e52e4d4be77cc4520a57af1a4a0d8222d1), which **enabled** file capabilities permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure these options are set correctly:

```
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE
CONFIG_USER_NS
CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES
CONFIG_VETH
CONFIG_MACVLAN

General setup  --->
    [*] Control Group support  --->
        [*]   Device controller for cgroups  (CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE)
    -*- Namespaces support  --->             (CONFIG_USER_NS)

Device Drivers --->
    Character devices --->
        -*- Unix98 PTY support
            [*]   Support multiple instances of devpts (CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES)
    [*] Network device support  --->
        -*-   Network core driver support
            <*>   Virtual ethernet pair device (CONFIG_VETH)
            <*>   MAC-VLAN support (CONFIG_MACVLAN)
```

I'm not sure that it is enough, but my system required at least these...